# What does "show up or cancel" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> A credit card number will be needed to hold the reservation, but will
>   not be charged unless you do not **show up or cancel** in advance of the
>   tour.
>   (https://gocity.com/san-antonio/en-us/attractions/texas-hill-country-lbj-ranch-tour)

The bold part is confusing. Does it mean:

> There are two instances where the card will be charged, which are:
>
> 1. when you do not show up on the day of the tour
> 2. when you do not cancel in advance of the tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A credit card number will be needed to hold the reservation, but will not be charged unless you do not show up or cancel in advance of the tour.

This makes perfect sense to me.

"*..unless you do not show up or cancel in advance*" is a case statement which becomes true if:

- you do **not** show up, or
- you do **not** cancel *in advance*.

The meaning of the entire statement is:

1. You must provide credit card details to make a reservation, but you will not be charged at that point. You will presumably be charged later when you meet that reservation.
2. The credit card *will* be charged if you either a) do not show up (so you simply do not arrive for the tour and never contacted them to tell them you would not be there), or b) fail to cancel *in advance* (for example, if you contacted them on the day of the tour to cancel that is not advance notice).

Presumably, if you did attend as intended you may be able to offer an alternative means of payment (ie a different card) which is why they can rightly say your card used for the reservation will *only* be charged in the circumstances above. Of course, you could use the same card for final payment.

Comment: Your bulleted part reads: They will not charge you if you either do not show up or you do not cancel. Obviously, they _will_ charge you if you do not cancel.

Comment: @Jan No, if you do not cancel **in advance**. If you cancel in advance then presumably you will not be charged. Not cancelling at all is covered in "not showing up".

Comment: Your bulleted part is not clear, because you didn't use it in the complete sentence.  Would you mind to edit that?

Comment: @Jan the point of the bulleted part is to break it down, not quote verbatim. I'm trying to show that the "not" applies to "not showing up" *and* "not cancelling in advance". What part of the sentence do you think I have omitted?

Comment: It seems we read the original sentence differently. You read it as "unless you do not show up or _do not_ cancel". I read it as "unless you do not show up or cancel." So, to me, "do not" applies only to "show up" but not to "cancel." Your second bullet reads to me: "We will not charge you if you do not cancel." I was just thinking, you can really clarify this, if you introduce the bulleted part with the actual preceding part of the sentence.

Comment: @Jan If you are reading it differently then you are imagining some punctuation that is not there. This seems quite clear to me. "Legal" language or "small print" is not always idiomatic speech but it *is* usually clear and unambiguous.

Comment: The original sentence says: "A credit card number will be needed to hold the reservation, but will not be charged unless _you do not show up or cancel..._." You say in your (non-numbered) bulleted part: "A credit card number will be needed to hold the reservation, but will not be charged unless _you do not show up or you **do not** cancel..._  You think that "do not" applies to both "show up" and "cancel," but I think it applies only to "show up." Your explanation, as I read it, means: "You will not be charged if you do not cancel." - but this is not true. Do we agree?

Comment: You did explain it correctly in your numbered bulleted part: The credit card will be charged if you either do not show up or fail to cancel in advance.

Comment: @Jan Every time you write "..if you do not cancel" you omit the words "*in advance*". It is not every cancellation that attracts a charge, it is only cancellations which are *not* "in advance". This makes a *huge* difference to the meaning. Sorry but I still don't see what is wrong with my answer as you keep misquoting.

Comment: Yes, I always thought "cancelled in advanced." Your explanation in the numbered part is very clear, but I find the non-numbered bulleted part part confusing. No issues, we can move on.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, it is the opposite. The card will be charged:

1. if you show up, because you have to pay the fee anyway;
2. if you cancel - you will probably pay a cancellation fee.

Now there is a question left: what will happen if you do not show up, but you do not explicitly cancel wither? Maybe this will count as a cancellation too, but the sentence does not clarify.

---

As @Jan stated in [another answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/211439/89027), the triple negation is a total mess and should normally be avoided at all costs. If the situation is real, you are better off sending an email ans asking for a clarification of the statement.

Answer (score -2):

This is really confusing because it's kind of triple negative 1) not be charged, 2) unless, 3) do not show up.

The two negatives (will not be charged + unless) make a positive: will be charged. So, your interpretation seems to be right: The card will be charged if you do not show up or if you do not cancel in advance.

If we take that their sentence is correct, it means you will be charged up *despite* not showing up. Like they say, it's not our business if you show up or not; we will charge you in any case, because you signed in and you didn't cancel. I think, this is realistically possible, because they usually charge you (or not) in the office, not at the place where you show up.